# Lua - changing 'stop' variable's value from within the for-loop, will it terminate as normal still?

Tags: for-loop, lua, infinite-loop

For example, if I do the following:

```lua
local iStop = 32
for i = 1, iStop do
  iStop = iStop + 1
end
```

Will the loop be guaranteed to run only 32 iterations, or is there any case it may run infinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [Lua Reference Manual 3.3.5: For statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

> ```
>  for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
>    var = var - step
>    while true do
>      var = var + step
>      if (step >= 0 and var > limit) or (step < 0 and var < limit) then
>        break
>      end
>      local v = var
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> ...
>
> All three control expressions are evaluated only once, before the loop
>   starts.

The loop will run 32 times. The actual loop limit is a copy of `iStop`'s value befor the loop starts and no matter what you do to `iStop` in the loop it will not affect the loop limit.